# Is $\mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{0\}$ separable for $2\leq p$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I thought this was indeed separable. I did not know how to proof this.
I wanted to proof this with a characteristic of a not separable space and then conclude that this is not possible so that it is separable.

So I want to prove that there does not exist a subspace A and B of $\mathbb{R}^p \backslash \{0\}$ , who are disjoint. With $ \bar{A}\bigcap B = A \bigcap \bar{B}=\emptyset$

But here I find it very difficult to do so, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Consider points with rational coordinates.

Comment: So just because $\mathbb{Q}^p\backslash\{0\}$ is dense in  $\mathbb{R}^p\backslash\{0\}$?

Comment: Yes, that is  the proof.